# Find the sum $6(-2.3x-5)+(4x+11)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused as to how you find the sum. I have already tried finding like terms and adding or subtracting them. What do I do?

Comment: Is "x" here an algebraic variable or is it the multiplication sign?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question to show explicitly "what you have already tried" and where you are stuck.

Comment: Distribute among the brackets to obtain $$6(-2.3x-5)+(4x+11)=-13.8x-30+4x+11$$

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: Distribute the $6$ to each term in $1$st parentheses: $6(-2.3x) - 6\cdot 5 = -13.8x - 30$.

**Step 2**: Combine like terms. Thus: $6(-2.3x-5)+(4x+11) = -13.8x-30+4x+11=-13.8x+4x-30+11=-9.8x-19$. Note that the $-9.8$ comes from $-13.8+4$, and the $-19$ comes from $-30+11$. Hope this helps.